# Adobe Type 1 Encryption Algorithm in Assembly

Tags: algorithm, file, assembly, encryption, tasm

I am trying to encrypt a text file using the adobe type 1 font encryption algorithm. However, I don't know how to properly implement the algorithm in assembly language. Please, help me if you can.

Here is the adobe type 1 font encryption algorithm:

```
 unsigned short int r;
 unsigned short int c1 =52845;
 unsigned short int c2 = 22719;


unsigned char eencrypt(char plain) unsigned char plain;
   {    unsigned char cipher; 

     cipher = (plain ^ (r >> 8));  
     r = (cipher + r) * c1 + c2;    
 return cipher; 
 }
```

Here is my code:

```
.model tiny
.data


filename db "file.txt", 0
bufferSize = 512
filehandle dw ?
buffer db bufferSize dup (0)

 r dw 0
c1 dw 52845
c2 dw 22719
cipher dw ?

message1 db 'Cannot open file. $' 
message2 db 'Cannot read file. $' 
message3 db 'Cannot close file. $' 



 .code
org 100h

 start:

call open
call read
call close
call Exit 

;procedures

 open:
  mov ah,3DH
  mov al,0
  mov dx, offset filename
  int 21h
  jc openErr
  mov filehandle, ax
  ret

   read:                        ;reads file
  mov ah, 3Fh
  mov bx, filehandle
  mov cx, bufferSize
  mov dx, offset buffer
  int 21h
  cmp ax,0
  jc readErr


;displays content of file
 call clear
 mov ah, 9
 mov dx, offset buffer
 int 21h
 ret 

close:
 mov ah, 3Eh
 mov bx, filehandle
int 21h
jc closeErr
ret

 encrypt:
; need loop to loop through each char, don't know how to do that 
        mov ax, [r]
        shr ax, 8          
        mov bl, [buffer]
        xor bh,bh    
        xor bx, ax       
        mov cipher, bx      
        mov dx, cipher     
        add dx, [r]       ;get error: extra characters on line
        imul dx, c1 
        add dx, c2 
        mov [r], dx     



 ;decrypt:

 clear: ;clears the screen

      mov ax,003h
      int 10h
      ret 
  Exit: 
  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h


newline:  ;prints a newline                           
        mov ah, 2                    
        mov dl, 0DH
        int 21h            
        mov dl, 0AH                 
        int 21h         
        ret

   ;error messages 

  openErr :
     call newline
    lea  DX,message1    ;set up pointer to error message
    mov  AH,9          ;display string function
    int  21H           ;DOS call
    stc               ;set error flag
    ret

 readErr :
    call newline
     lea  DX,message2    ;set up pointer to error message
     mov  AH,9          ;display string function
    int  21H           ;DOS call
    stc               ;set error flag
    ret

closeErr :
  call newline
  lea  DX,message3    ;set up pointer to error message
  mov  AH,9          ;display string function
  int  21H           ;DOS call
  stc               ;set error flag
  ret
```

end start

Comment: As the `r` is uninitialized, it may contain some unknown value -> it will be impossible to decrypt the result.

Comment: @Ped7g what do you suggest? Should I initialize r to any value? Or a specific value?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't provide you with that C example. *If* `r` in the C example is global variable, then it *is* initialized to zero. In C/C++ it is always easier to read the source, when it states things explicitly, so I would do `r = 0;` any way, even for globals. Then in assembly you may do `r dw 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;encrypt:
; need loop to loop through each char, don't know how to do that 
;mov ax, r
;shr ax, 8           r>>8
;mov bl, buffer      bl = buffer
```

`buffer` is symbolic address, not value in the buffer. Use `mov bl,[buffer]` to read the value from memory. And if you want to loop over full buffer content, put that address into some register, `si` is often favoured for keeping pointer to the source of data (because it is hardcoded in `lods` instructions, and "s" may be read as "source"). If you are C++ compiler, you don't care, and you pick any spare register you have, without considering it's name.

```
;xor bx, ax          bx = buffer ^(r>>8)
```

`bh` was not set and may be anything, ruining your calculation. Either do `xor bx,bx` before loading the `bl` from buffer, or `xor bh,bh` to clear `bh` only (tiny fraction slower on modern x86 because it must then combine `bh`+`bl` into `bx`), or use `movzx bx,byte ptr [buffer]` in previous step to zero-extend the char value into word value.

```
;mov cipher, bx      cipher = buffer^(r>>8)
```

Label `cipher` was defined ahead of `db ?`, but here you are writing two bytes into memory, so it will also overwrite first byte of `message1` string. And I strongly suggest to use `[]` every time you write into memory, even when TASM/MASM allows this kind of syntax, but I find it difficult to read (seeing `[cipher]` will make my brain automatically think "memory access" even with quick glance on source).

```
;mov cx, c1
```

`c1` and `c2` can be `EQU`, so they will compile as intermediate values directly into code.

```
;add cx, c2
```

That's not, what the C encrypt does (multiplication has priority over addition).

```
;mov dx, cipher
```

Again you treat `cipher` as word, which makes sense, but it's against the `db ?` (so the `db` needs fixing, not code here).

```
;add dx, r
;imul dx, cx
```

I would use `[]` brackets around `r` again, and the multiplication/addition order is of course wrong.

Not a bad try, but don't hesitate to uncomment that piece of code, pre-set registers with some debug values, and jump straight to it, open the binary in debugger, and single-step over it to verify it works as you did want. You would probably quickly find all those things I wrote above.

Then just turn it into loop (use any ASM book/tutorial with some example about working with arrays/strings, learn to use pointers, then it should be not that hard to finish).

Comment: Ok. I made some of the changes you recommended. However, I don't understand your comments about cipher. Can you please elaborate? What exactly do I have to do?

Comment: @ajstc Use TASM command line option `/l` to generate listing file. Check how the part of source around `cipher` definition is compiled. `cipher db ?` will produce 1 byte of machine code, followed by the string of `message1`, so the next byte has value `'C'` (from "Cannot" word). If you do `mov ax,1234h` `mov [cipher],ax`, the memory at address `cipher` will be set to byte value `34h`, and the memory at address `message1` will be set to byte value `12h` (overwriting the original `'C'` value, damaging that string). In asm it's important to reserve correct memory amount, so `dw ?` for cipher.

Comment: Ok. Now I get the error , Extra characters on line,  for the line: add dx, [r] .

Comment: @ajstc that doesn't make much sense, verify the line is exactly just that `add dx,[r]` (maybe even write it from scratch, to make sure there's ordinary comma, and space, and brackets, etc)  ... in worst case try to use longer label name, like `rrrr` to avoid some reserved word clash, but I can't recall `r` being reserved.

Comment: I deleted the line and rewrote it but now I'm getting the error for the next line which is:   imul dx, c1

Comment: @ajstc which error? "extra character" again? I can't read your mind. `imul dx,[c1]` should work and IIRC is legal instruction in 16b real mode. If it's "extra character" again, write above it the same thing from scratch through keyboard, save the file, open in hex-viewer, and compare the two lines, where the second line differs. Maybe you have some "nice" comma used for printing books instead of ordinary ASCII `,`, or there's some borked unicode character at the end of line...

Comment: yes, "extra character" again.  Right now, I am using dosbox to assemble the program. I don't know how to use a hex viewer.

Comment: @ajstc dosbox is mapping your real drive, so you can check the file also outside of dosbox. Hexviewer... don't know what OS you are using, in linux there's many of them, I have in command line "hexdump". Or just try rewrite one character at time (starting from the commas/etc) to see when it will work. Or copy the whole line as is here into comment and hope it will copy the offending character without any change, so I will see it too.

Comment: The line is :       imul dx, c1

Comment: @ajstc here on the web there's no extra char or weird one, should work. Either you didn't manage to copy whole line with all the chars (even hidden ones), or the stackoverflow comments filtered it out. Any way, it's very cumbersome to resolve this kind of bug here, just rewrite those offending lines from scratch, if you can't figure out where's that extra character hidden, but make sure you are hunting correct line, this bug is either weird char due to editor used, or wrong syntax like `mov ax,ax,ax`, etc.